# Trusted Root Certificates in DotNet Core on Linux (RHEL 7.1)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, .net-core, redhat, root-certificate

I'm currently deploying a .net-core web-api to an docker container on rhel 7.1. 
Everything works as expected, but from my application I need to call other services via https and those hosts use certificates signed by self-maintained root certificates.

In this constellation I get ssl-errors while calling this services (ssl-not valid) and therefore I need to install this root-certificate in the docker-container or somehow use the root-certificate in the .net-core application.

How can this be done? Is there a best practice to handle this situation? Will .net-core access the right keystore on the rhel-system?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since .NET Core uses OpenSSL on linux, you need to set up your linux environment in the container so that OpenSSL will pick up the certificate.

This is done by (+ Dockerfile examples):

1. Copying the the certificate `.crt` file to a location that `update-ca-certificates` will scan for trusted certificates - e.g. `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` or on RHEL `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/`:

   ```
    COPY myca.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
   ```
2. Invoking `update-ca-certificates`:

   ```
    RUN update-ca-certificates
   ```

Comment: Thanks: this got me in the right direction! The folders and commands in RHEL are a little different: /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/ for copying the certificate and update-ca-trust for updating the truststores.

Comment: Ah yes I forgot to check that distro, updated answer a little

Comment: thank you so much for this! i've been trying to do something like this for years and this was absolutely painless!