# Unable to validate SMTP certificate on Ubuntu, but works for Windows

Tags: ssl, .net-core, ubuntu-18.04, lets-encrypt, mailkit

I'm trying to send email using MailKit through provider's SMTP server using valid **Let's Encrypt Authority X3** certificate. On Windows everything works great, but when sending from Ubuntu I get certificate error:

> MailKit.Security.SslHandshakeException: An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection.
>
> One possibility is that you are trying to connect to a port which does not support SSL/TLS.
>
> The other possibility is that the SSL certificate presented by the server is not trusted by the system for one or more of the following reasons:
>
> 1. The server is using a self-signed certificate which cannot be verified.
> 2. **The local system is missing a Root or Intermediate certificate needed to verify the server's certificate.** *(I believe this is my problem?)*
> 3. The certificate presented by the server is expired or invalid.

When I dig deeper into X509Chain status it says

> RevocationStatusUnknown unable to get certificate CRL

Up until now I've been ignoring this error, but I'd rather have the underlying problem fixed and I don't know what exactly I'm missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your .NET application on Mono, there's a Mono FAQ that explains how to import root certificates into your certificate store: https://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/security/

If you are using .NET Core CLR, you might find this answer helpful: [Trusted Root Certificates in DotNet Core on Linux (RHEL 7.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44159793/trusted-root-certificates-in-dotnet-core-on-linux-rhel-7-1)